# Using a DTO as the model for a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dto

If you see at the top of an ASP.NET MVC view:

```
<% var dto = (MyDto)Model; %>
```

...is something wrong? It doesn't feel right to me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not need to cast the type in this way for a strongly typed view. If the view inherits from `ViewPage<MyDto>` then the Model property will be of type `MyDto`.

If the view is not strongly typed then the Model property is of type `object` so you would need to cast it.

It makes sense to use a strongly typed view in this case though

Answer (score 2):

The question is: Is it good to store DTO objects as the model for View?
My answer is: it's depends. DTO should have only one behavior: storing data. So when you using DTO object only for displaying it on View: then it's OK.

View Model is designed to store more compliated objects that contains multiple behaviors, but there is no fault to store DTO's.

Comment: Can you give an example when the object sent to the view needs more complex functionality?

Comment: For example: some ActiveRecord object